# How to use SearchView in Toolbar from all fragments

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments

My app has a Navigation Drawer as well as a Toolbar with 2 menu items. One of the items is SearchView...

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
```

method is placed in MainActivity and the Toolbar is apparently visible from all the fragments of my app.
To make the SearchView usable from all the fragments I have been using this lovely method:

```
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu)
```

The method is basically in every single fragment of my app and all the searching logic is repeating in all the fragments and it looks like this:

```
public class ChampagneFragment extends Fragment {

private View champagneView;
private RecyclerView champagneList;
private ItemsAdapter itemsAdapter;
private List<NewModel> list;

private DatabaseOpenHelper databaseOpenHelper;


public ChampagneFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    champagneView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_champagne, container, false);

    champagneList = champagneView.findViewById(R.id.champagneRVList);
    champagneList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    return champagneView;
}


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    databaseOpenHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(getContext());

    //Check exists database
    File database = getContext().getDatabasePath(DatabaseOpenHelper.DBNAME);
    if(false == database.exists()) {
        databaseOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        //Copy db
        if(copyDatabase(getContext())) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Copy database success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Copy data error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

    }
    //Get product list in db when db exists
    list = databaseOpenHelper.getChampagne();
    //Init adapter
    itemsAdapter = new ItemsAdapter(getContext(), list);
    //Set adapter for listview
    champagneList.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);

}

// copy SQLite data
private boolean copyDatabase(Context context) {
    try {

        InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open(DatabaseOpenHelper.DBNAME);
        String outFileName = DatabaseOpenHelper.DBLOCATION + DatabaseOpenHelper.DBNAME;
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[]buff = new byte[1024];
        int length = 0;
        while ((length = inputStream.read(buff)) > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buff, 0, length);
        }
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        Log.w("MainActivity","DB copied");
        return true;
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

 //======================SEARCHING FUNCTIONALITY=========================

//fetching SearchView    
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

    MenuItem mSearchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) mSearchMenuItem.getActionView();

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            // filtering data
            if (newText != null && TextUtils.getTrimmedLength(newText) > 0) {
                newText = newText.toLowerCase();
                List<NewModel> myList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (NewModel newModel : list) {

                    String title = newModel.getTitle().toLowerCase();
                    String description = newModel.getDescription().toLowerCase();
                    if (title.contains(newText) || description.contains(newText)) {

                        myList.add(newModel);
                        onSerach();
                    }

                }

                itemsAdapter.setFilter(myList);
            }
            else {

                list = databaseOpenHelper.getChampagne();
                itemsAdapter = new ItemsAdapter(getContext(), list);
                champagneList.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
                itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}

//getting data from search table in SQLite
public void onSerach(){

    databaseOpenHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(getContext());

    //Check exists database
    File database = getContext().getDatabasePath(DatabaseOpenHelper.DBNAME);
    if(false == database.exists()) {
        databaseOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        //Copy db
        if(copyDatabase(getContext())) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Copy database success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Copy data error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

    }
    //Get product list in db when db exists
    list = databaseOpenHelper.getSearch();
    //Init adapter
    itemsAdapter = new ItemsAdapter(getContext(), list);
    //Set adapter for listview
    champagneList.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
}
```

}

Firstly I had tried to filter data and show it in a new list from the MainActivty, but then I couldn't use SearchView from fragments... So after a while, I had decided to do that this way. But somehow for me, it seems like a bad practice... What do you think?
How could I do it differently so that I don't have many repetitive lines of codes and to make it more efficient?

Comment: almost every time you have repetitive code in classes you need to use inheritance

Comment: Bahman, thank you! Let me read the documentation for inheritance... Honestly know nothing about it! I am still a beginner at the beginning :) But anyway useful info, so I know what to look for!

Comment: @Bahman, I was reading the documentation and I definitely understood the purpose of using inheritance. But still, I can't get how to inherit just some methods from the base fragment... In this case, I want to inherit onPrepareOptionsMenu() and onSearch() methods.... Do you have any instructions?

Comment: @Bahman, thanks a lot! You taught me something new today! I have tried my best to make this as efficiently as possible. Have a look if you find the time!

Answer (score 0):

```
/***
 * Base class ChampagneBaseFragment extends Fragment
***/   
public abstract class ChampagneBaseFragment extends Fragment{

  // here override any Fragment method that has same code in all childs
  // here put variables used by methods of this class
  // if you want to read or write to this variables in child class 
  // then you have to make them public or protected
  public void onSerach(){
   // your onSearch code that is same in childs
  }

  @Override
  public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu) {
   // your onPrepareOptionsMenu code that is same in childs
  }
  // other common functions...
}


/***
 * Child class ChampagneFragment extends ChampagneBaseFragment 
***/   
public class ChampagneFragment extends ChampagneBaseFragment {// extends ChampagneBaseFragment 

// here you are using methods of ChampagneBaseFragment 
// you can use them without changing them
// or you can override methods of ChampagneBaseFragment and call super to use them
// then add your code below super call


}
```

Answer (score 0):

After implementation, this is my Fragment class that inherits BasaFragment class

```
public class ChampagneFragment extends BaseFragment {

private View champagneView;
private RecyclerView champagneList;
private ItemsAdapter itemsAdapter;
private List<NewModel> list;

private DatabaseOpenHelper databaseOpenHelper;


public ChampagneFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    champagneView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_champagne, container, false);

    champagneList = champagneView.findViewById(R.id.champagneRVList);
    champagneList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    databaseOpenHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(getContext());

    //Get product list in db when db exists
    list = databaseOpenHelper.getChampagne();
    //Init adapter
    itemsAdapter = new ItemsAdapter(getContext(), list);
    //Set adapter for listview
    champagneList.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);


    return champagneView;
}


@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

    MenuItem mSearchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) mSearchMenuItem.getActionView();

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (newText != null && TextUtils.getTrimmedLength(newText) > 0) {
                newText = newText.toLowerCase();
                List<NewModel> myList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (NewModel newModel : list) {

                    String title = newModel.getTitle().toLowerCase();
                    String description = newModel.getDescription().toLowerCase();
                    if (title.contains(newText) || description.contains(newText)) {

                        myList.add(newModel);
                        onSerach();
                    }

                }

                itemsAdapter.setFilter(myList);
            }
            else {

                list = databaseOpenHelper.getChampagne();
                itemsAdapter = new ItemsAdapter(getContext(), list);
                champagneList.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
                itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}


@Override
public void onSerach() {
    super.onSerach();

    list = databaseOpenHelper.getSearch();
    itemsAdapter = new ItemsAdapter(getContext(), list);
    champagneList.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
}
```

}

And the class that's being inherited from, BaseFragment class

```
public abstract class BaseFragment extends Fragment {


public DatabaseOpenHelper databaseOpenHelper;
public RecyclerView recyclerView;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.base_fragment, container, false);

    databaseOpenHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(getContext());

    //Check exists database
    File database = getContext().getDatabasePath(DatabaseOpenHelper.DBNAME);
    if(false == database.exists()) {
        databaseOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        //Copy db
        if(copyDatabase(getContext())) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Copy database succes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Copy data error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //return;
        }

    }


    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.baseFragmentRCV);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    return view;
}


public boolean copyDatabase(Context context) {
    try {

        InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open(DatabaseOpenHelper.DBNAME);
        String outFileName = DatabaseOpenHelper.DBLOCATION + DatabaseOpenHelper.DBNAME;
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[]buff = new byte[1024];
        int length = 0;
        while ((length = inputStream.read(buff)) > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buff, 0, length);
        }
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        Log.w("MainActivity","DB copied");
        return true;
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}


public void onSerach(){

    databaseOpenHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(getContext());

    //Check exists database
    File database = getContext().getDatabasePath(DatabaseOpenHelper.DBNAME);
    if(false == database.exists()) {
        databaseOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        //Copy db
        if(copyDatabase(getContext())) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Copy database success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Copy data error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

    }

}
```

}

So I've removed onStart() method and moved those lines of code below onCreateView()... The part for checking if data exists is in BaseFragment class so now in my fragments I am just getting product list from a database because each fragment has its own list. As well as for the search() method I've done the same thing. Method for copy data from the SQLite database has placed in the BaseFragment class. The only thing that I couldn't get done was onPrepareOptionsMenu() method I don't know why but in this line for (NewModel newModel : list) list was returning null...